# How to stop re-evaluation of array in for loop

Tags: perl, for-loop

```
use feature 'say';
@arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

for $x (@arr)
{
    print $x;
    @arr = (6,5,4,3,2,1) if $x == 3;
}
```

For the above code, perl will produce output: `123321`

Is there any way to stop perl re-evaluating the array in the loop so that the output is `123456` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Produce a list to iterate over

```
@ary = 1..6;

for $x (eval { @ary }) 
{
    print $x;
    @ary = (6,5,4,3,2,1); 
}                          # --> 123456
```

I expect this to be curiosity or experimentation, but let me still comment: if there is a practical goal behind it there are certainly better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shallow copy of an array and dereference it,

```
use feature 'say';
@arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

for $x (@{[ @arr ]})
{
    print $x;
    @arr = (6,5,4,3,2,1) if $x == 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the last command if you want to reassign the array and then exit the loop.  The last command will immediately exit the loop.

```
use feature 'say';
@arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

for $x (@arr)
{
  print $x;
  if ( 3 == $x ) 
  {
    @arr = (6,5,4,3,2,1);
    last;
  }
}
```

then @arr will be the assigned array and will not be evaluated.

Link to information on the last command:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html

Comment: I think he wanted output '123456' though.